# Why doesn't try-catch resolve the warning in unchecked generics casts?

Tags: java, generics, try-catch, clone, suppress-warnings

Consider the following [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve):

```
public class MyClass {
    private LinkedList<Foo> myList = new LinkedList<Foo>();

    // Some irrevelant stuff which includes loading myList

    public void myMethod() {
        LinkedList<Foo> newList;

        try {
             newList = (LinkedList<Foo>) myList.clone();
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
             // do something in case java screws up
        }
    }
}
```

I know that you can get rid of the warning by using `@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")` but why doesn't the `try/catch` block work? Is it a waste of time and energy to put the `try/catch` in there?

Comment: "_but none of them mention using try/catch in this type of situation_", then why do you think it would work in this case?

Comment: Are you actually trying to catch warnings?

Comment: Dude!! Try catch is not meant to solve your possible/actual programming anomalies. It's rather meant for getting through the run time hacks. In your case it's pretty obvious that the cloned object conforms to the type being casted to. So a try catch is needless here.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

That won't work, because you are not getting a ClassCastException for this.

The erased type of the list cannot be checked at runtime.

You might get a ClassCastException when you try to get something out of the List (and that turns out not to be a Foo), but the List itself is just a LinkedList (without knowing what its element types can be).

An instance of `LinkedList<Foo>` looks exactly like a `LinkedList<Bar>` at runtime.

The reason for the warning is that the runtime system cannot guarantee that the cast you are doing is correct (it can check the LinkedList part, but not the generic type).

Answer (score 0):

I think that when you are explicitly casting anything, the compiler doesn't check for unchecked exceptions. The compiler relies on the code writer for explicit type casting.

Answer (score 0):

**-** `Erasure` is a process in which the `Type Parameters and Arguments` are **removed from the Class within and the methods,etc.**

**-** `Box<String>` becomes `Box` , this is known as **Raw Type**, where the **Generic classes and interfaces are stripped off their Type Arguments during the Compile time,**

**-** And this is done so that during `Run time` a **back ward compatibility** can be obtained to those codes which **doesn't** used the `Generics`.

**So thats the reason this is going unchecked.**